# Projecting a field that doesn't always exist

Tags: mongodb, null, projection

Is there a way to project fields that may or may not exist? Such as having it defined as `null` or undefined?

For instance, I have a query with:

```
$project: {
  date: 1,
  name: "$person.name",
  age: "$person.age"
}
```

Not all documents are guaranteed to have a `$person.age`, but instead of the ones without an age being returned as `{ date: Today, name: "Bill" }`, I would like it to say `{ date: Today, name: "Bill", age: null }` or something similar.

Is there a better way than just iterating through the data afterwards and creating the fields if they don't exist?

Comment: What is the difference between having a field with a null value and not having the field at all?

Comment: Some of the modules I am using it with that export it to an excel file or print it in a grid leave the column empty if the first document doesn't have a particular field that appears later.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use `$ifNull`

```
  $project: {
     date: 1,
     name: "$person.name",
     age: { $ifNull: [ "$person.age", "null" ] }
  }
```

You can find more about it [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/)

Comment: It looks like $ifNull only works with aggregate, and not with find

Answer (score 3):

This is where [**`$ifNull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) expression comes into the fray. From the [**docs**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/), `$ifNull`:

> Evaluates an expression and returns the value of the expression if the
>   expression evaluates to a non-null value. If the expression evaluates
>   to a null value, including instances of undefined values or missing
>   fields, returns the value of the replacement expression.

In your case, the following will use the `$ifNull` expression to return either the non-null `$person.age` field value or the string "Unspecified" if the age field is null or does not exist:

```
 $project: {
     date: 1,
     name: "$person.name",         
     age: { $ifNull: [ "$person.age", "Unspecified" ] }
 }
```

Comment: anyway to use $ifNull with an else clause? I am looking to add a boolean field with true/false based on another field existing or not null.

Answer (score 3):

Starting in `Mongo 5.3`, it's a nice use case for the new [`$fill`](https://docs.mongodb.com/upcoming/reference/operator/aggregation/fill/#fill-missing-field-values-with-a-constant-value) aggregation operator:

```
// { name: "Bill", age: 23 }
// { name: "Peter" }
db.collection.aggregate(
  { $fill: { output: { age: { value: "Unspecified" } } } }
)
// { name: "Bill",  age: 23 }
// { name: "Peter", age: "Unspecified" }
```

Missing values or values set to `null` are `fill`ed with the given constant `Unspecified`.

---

Concerning your exact scenario, you can go for:

```
// { person: { name: "Bill", age: 23 } }
// { person: { name: "Peter" } }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $project: { name: "$person.name" , age: "$person.age" } },
  { $fill: { output: { "age": { value: "Unspecified" } } } }
])
// { name: "Bill",  age: 23 }
// { name: "Peter", age: "Unspecified" }
```